# Subscriber callback function isn't invoked

Tags: ros, roslaunch, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two publishers publish array of integers to two different topics (Topic_1 and Topic_2)
and a third node subscribes to these two topics.

```
  ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int32MultiArray>("Topic_1",1000);
    std_msgs::Int32MultiArray vec;
   
      ROS_INFO("Array elements from file [array1.txt] are published to Topic_1:\n");
      ifstream infile("array1.txt");
    
      while(infile >> temp)
          vec.data.push_back(temp);
    
      publisher.publish(vec);
      ros::spin();
      return 0;
    }
```

Here is the code for second publisher

```
...
...
 ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int32MultiArray>("Topic_2",1000);

    std_msgs::Int32MultiArray vec2;
    ROS_INFO("Array elements from file [array2.txt] are published to Topic_2:\n");

  ifstream infile("array2.txt");
  while(infile >> temp)
      vec2.data.push_back(temp);
 
  publisher.publish(vec2);
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the one for subscriber:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<std_msgs/Int32MultiArray.h>

void sort();
 
void callback_1(const std_msgs::Int32MultiArray::ConstPtr& vec1)
{ 
  ROS_INFO("Vector recieved! over Topic_1\n");
}

void callback_2(const std_msgs::Int32MultiArray::ConstPtr& vec2)
{
  ROS_INFO("Vector recieved! over Topic_2\n");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

  ROS_INFO("Reading the vectors from both the topics");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::Subscriber sub_1 = nh.subscribe("Topic_1",1000,callback_1);
  ros::Subscriber sub_2 = nh.subscribe("Topic_2",1000,callback_2);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

But `ROS_INFO("Vector recieved! over Topic_1\n");`statements are not at all executed.
I even wrote a launch file to start these three nodes but the above statement is not executed.
But when I run `rosnode list`, all the three nodes are listed and even both the topics are displayed when I run `rostopic list`
What could probably be going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228018/subscriber-callback-function-isn%27t-invoked/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-03-02**:
Have you tried replacing spin() with a while loop and ros::spinOnce() ? Subscription will not require a while loop, just spinOnce will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you "immediately" publish your messages after advertising the topic. Your publishers are probably not up when sending the messages, thus they are just dropped.

There is no built-in way of reliably waiting on the publishers to be up. However, you can latch the topic if messages are not published repeatedly / with a fixed rate ([see 1.2](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers)):

```
ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int32MultiArray>("Topic_1",1000, true);
```

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2016-03-02**:
Thanks a lot!! That worked